# Collapse all lines to one line in VS2019?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I there any way to do the following in VS2019?

Say I have code that looks like this:

```
    Somefunction();
    SomeStatement;
    SomeOtherFunction();
```

I want to select these lines, and quickly and easily press a button or key and have it produce this (based on semicolon):

```
    Somefunction();SomeStatement;SomeOtherFunction();
```

...And also reverse it.
It's sort of like collapsing the code except it'll be remembered between instances and also compatible with other systems.

Is there any way to make this happen without writing a whole extension?

Comment: Why on earth would you want that? It won't improve the performance of your code. It won't reduce your compile times in any meaningful way (probably the "minifying" process will take more time than the compiler saves parsing it). It will make the code harder to read. So *why*???   But, you could probably abuse clang-format horribly to do something like that, but I really don't see why you would.

Comment: @JesperJuhl  Some people just hate white space.  I get it.  I am the opposite - formatting my code for easier understanding and debugging.  But to each their own.  I've broken down my printf style function calls to multiple lines utilizing built-in string literal concatination by the compiler so that my format string literal expression is more readable, line broken at "...\n"<CR> or sentences "blah blah %d blah.  "<CR>.

Comment: The proper way to do it is to refactor those codes into smaller functions. But if you really must you can abuse find and replace by using regular expression to look for ; + newline and replace it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Eidt->Advanced->Join Lines:

```
Shift+Alt+L,Shift+Alt+J
```

[image]

Comment: That works-- thank you.  Is there a reverse also, to unjoin them?